# Show duplicates in multiple columns in UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with the query below.

This query shows all open invoices [OINV] and credit notes [ORIN].
As a result, I want to see the duplicates of CardCode and DocTotal.

Here's an example:

```
CardCode    CardName        DocTotal
12          Name12              10
12          Name12              20
13          Name13              10
14          Name14              15
14          Name14              15
15          Name15              10
16          Name16              15
17          Name17              20
17          Name17              15
18          Name18              14
19          Name19              33
19          Name19              33
19          Name19              33
```

The result:

```
14          Name14              15
14          Name14              15
19          Name19              33
19          Name19              33
19          Name19              33
```

Query so far:

```
SELECT 
CardCode, 
CardName, 
DocTotal

FROM 
(
SELECT 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName],
T0.[DocNum],  
T0.[DocTotal] 

FROM 
ORIN T0 

WHERE 
T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName],
T0.[DocNum],  
T0.[DocTotal] 

FROM 
OINV T0 

WHERE 
T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
) as T1
```

Comment: Please update the tags with the RDBMS platform you are using. Some now support the `QUALIFY()` clause which would be the best way to attack this if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an RDBMS platform that supports the `QUALIFY` clause (Teradata, Snowflake, Databricks) then you can add the following to the end of your existing SQL:

```
 QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardCode, DocTotal) > 1
```

If you are in any other RDBMS like sql-server, mysql, postgres, etc. then you'll need to stick your existing sql in a subquery and add the `COUNT(*) OVER...` to your `SELECT` and then filter with a traditional WHERE clause:

```
SELECT CardCode, CardName, DocTotal
FROM 
    (
        SELECT CardCode,
            CardName,
            DocTotal,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardCode, DocTotal) as duplicates
        FROM (
                SELECT T0.[CardCode],
                    T0.[CardName],
                    T0.[DocNum],
                    T0.[DocTotal]
                FROM ORIN T0
                WHERE T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT T0.[CardCode],
                    T0.[CardName],
                    T0.[DocNum],
                    T0.[DocTotal]
                FROM OINV T0
                WHERE T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
            ) as T1
    ) as dt 
WHERE duplicates > 1
```

Adding the [`OVER ()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to the `COUNT()` aggregation function turns it into a "Window Function". With the `PARTITION` clause we state how to bucket the records in the result set and then with `COUNT()` we count how many are in that bucket. If that count is greater than one, then we keep it for output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function

```sql
WITH unioned AS (
    SELECT 
      T0.[CardCode], 
      T0.[CardName],
      T0.[DocTotal] 
    FROM 
    ORIN T0 
    WHERE T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      T0.[CardCode], 
      T0.[CardName],
      T0.[DocTotal] 
    FROM OINV T0 
    WHERE T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
),
Counted AS (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY u.CardCode, u.DocTotal) AS count
    FROM unioned u
)
SELECT c.*
FROM Counted c
WHERE c.count > 1;
```

Or just use an inner join, but this will put the duplicates on the same row.

```sql
SELECT 
  OINV.CardCode,
  OINV.CardName AS OINV_CardName,
  OINV.DocTotal,
  ORIN.CardName AS ORIN_CardName
FROM ORIN 
JOIN OINV
  ON OINV.CardCode = ORIN.CardCode
 AND OINV.DocTotal = ORIN.DocTotal
WHERE ORIN.DocStatus = 'O'
  AND OINV.DocStatus = 'O';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by joining the dataset from your subquery with the list of *CardCode* and *DocTotal* that have duplicates :

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT T0.[cardcode], 
                T0.[cardname], 
                T0.[doctotal] 
         FROM   orin T0 
         WHERE  T0.[docstatus] = 'O' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT T0.[cardcode], 
                T0.[cardname], 
                T0.[doctotal] 
         FROM   oinv T0 
         WHERE  T0.[docstatus] = 'O') 
SELECT t.* 
FROM   data t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT cardcode, 
                          doctotal 
                   FROM   mytable 
                   GROUP  BY cardcode, 
                             doctotal 
                   HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS s 
               ON s.cardcode = t.cardcode 
                  AND s.doctotal = t.doctotal;
```

Results :

```
CardCode    CardName    DocTotal
14          Name14      15
14          Name14      15
19          Name19      33
19          Name19      33
19          Name19      33
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qloRkk6C)